# Reading and Writing a new line from a file to another in Python

Tags: python, file-io, newline

I'm trying to read from a file and write into another. The problem arises when I'm trying to preserve newlines from the original file to the new one.

```
def caesar_encrypt(orig , shift):
  enctextCC = open("CCencoded.txt" , 'w')
  for i in range(len(orig)):
    for j in range(len(orig[i])):
        curr = orig[i][j]   
        if ord(curr) == 10:
            enctextCC.write("\n") //doesn't work :(
        elif ord(curr) < 97:
            enctextCC.write(curr)

        elif ord(curr)+shift > 122:
            enctextCC.write(chr(ord(curr)+shift-26))

        elif ord(curr)+shift >= 97 & ord(curr)+ shift <= 122  :
            enctextCC.write(chr(ord(curr)+shift))

enctextCC.close()
```

Any suggestions as to what is going wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT:**  The solution is to add the newline in at the end of the outer for loop. Since I'm reading a list of lists, the inner loop is basically a single line.  So it should looks like this:

```
    def caesar_encrypt(orig , shift):
  enctextCC = open("CCencoded.txt" , 'w')
  for i in range(len(orig)):
    for j in range(len(orig[i])):
        curr = orig[i][j]   
        if ord(curr) < 97:
            enctextCC.write(curr)

        elif ord(curr)+shift > 122:
            enctextCC.write(chr(ord(curr)+shift-26))

        elif ord(curr)+shift >= 97 & ord(curr)+ shift <= 122  :
            enctextCC.write(chr(ord(curr)+shift))
    enctextCC.write("\n")

enctextCC.close()
```

Comment: *What* doesn't work? How so, and what do you actually want to do?

Comment: It looks like you are JUST writing newlines to the new file...

Comment: I have a few more cases which work, it's just when I'm trying to preserve the newline character it breaks.

Comment: You should take a look at `str.maketrans` and `str.translate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are doing it wrong

```
out_file = open("output.txt", "w")
for line in open("input.txt", "r"):
    out_file.write(line)
    out_file.write("\n")
```

*Note that we don't check for newline endings because we fetch items one line at a time, so we are sure that after a line we have read follows a newline*

But why do you need to do this instead of a normal copy?

**Edit**: in case all you need is copy a file, use this:

```
from shutil import copy
copy("input.txt", "output.txt")
```

In case you need to read whole file, use the `read()` function, like this:

```
file_data = open("input.txt", "r").read()
# manipulate the data ...
output = open("output.txt", "w")
output.write(file_data)
output.close()
```

**EDIT 2**: so, if you are trying to map other ASCII values to each character, you are doing it right, except for:

- You forgot to write other characters, you will only output `\n` characters
- Make sure you actually *read* the newlines, since `readlines()` and iterating through the file don't return newlines.

Your code will look more like this:

```
for j in range(len(orig[i])):
        curr = orig[i][j]
        if ord(curr) == 10:  
            enctextCC.write(curr)
        else:
            enctextCC.write(transformed(curr))
```

Comment: This is what I have except instead of transformed() I have the other if cases. The enctextCC.write(curr) for newline still isn't working though.

Comment: then maybe you are not reading the newlines - check that by adding a `print '\n' in orig`.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the files in binary mode to preserve the EOL:

```
with open(filenameIn, 'rb') as inFile:
 with open(filenameOut, 'wb') as outFile:
  for line in inFile:
   outFile.write(line)
```

Comment: I would vote for this answer except for the inexplicable call to .upper().  Why is that there?  I don't see a requirement for it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you read a file by lines you are implicitly splitting the file up by lines and this discards the newlines.  If you want newlines you should simply append a newline manually:

```
enctextCC.write(curr + "\n")
```

Your other alternative would be to read in the lines from the first file using the [`readline`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline) function wich preserves the trailing newline.

Comment: Hmmm, nothing happened. I can't use  the readline function because I need to manipulate each character in each line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're getting your input...this works fine:

```
input = open('filename', 'r')
lines = input.readlines()
output = open('outfile', 'w')
output.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: I'm making a series of ciphers which requires me to get single characters then map them to other ascii values, then write the new mapped character into a new file.

Comment: Should still work fine; just operate on `lines`. It includes newlines.